# The employer is refusing to pay the full salary

Tags: india, employer, salary, employment

I did some freelance work for one India based organization. There is one contract signed by me accepting all their terms and conditions (it was printed on a plain A4 sheet of paper).

From start till the end of the work they have not raised a single issue via email or phone. They never notified me about the content or behavior or anything but on payment day they deducted a huge amount from my pay stating different reasons. These reasons are not mentioned in the agreement like it will deduct payment based on that.

The question is: How can I make them pay me completely? Is there a government body who can stand on my side inquire/investigate them and so I can get my money?

Are these portals good enough to complain:

https://consumerhelpline.gov.in/

https://pgportal.gov.in/

Comment: Yes, the governs body is the court - you sue them.

Comment: Were they an "employer" or a "client"?? The term "freelance work" would indicate that they are **not** an "employer". Independent contracting is quite different than actual employment.

Comment: You are right, I worked for a client who sent me to their client's location for work.

Comment: Query what kind of deductions they were. Were they merely tax withholding? Was there any contractual basis for the deductions at all? Did you have other transactions with them that are being set off?

Answer (score 2):

Yes , you can sue them in the court, before the appropriate forum. But before that it would be better if you share your appointment letter or any agreement that you have entered with your employer.

Answer (score 1):

The two portals you mention will not help. The first is for consumers, but you are a business person not a consumer. The second seems to be for people complaining about government services, but your client is not a government service.

As Joginder has said, the only recourse you have is through the courts. That's not a good place to be, but there it is.